# php/ajax JSON respone returns [object, Object] once parsed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

When I try to parse a response from an AJAX request as JSON, I get [object, Object] values instead of the actual ones returned before parsing the response. What could I have done wrong?

I have one script named "apply.php" which has the a short application and an AJAX request called when the user selects a town. There is another script named "suburb.php" which retrieves stored suburbs in the database that are under the selected town. The second script is called when the users selects/changes a town.

In the "apply.php" script I have a JavaScript alert that display the response, which I then parses as JSON. After passing the response, [object, Object] is returned instead of the actual values, thus disabling me from reading the JSON key values.

Using the values without parsing them does not help either. I tried checking for question that relate to my problem without any luck.

Your assistance will be greatly appreciated.

apply.php

```
<?php
$dbcon = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Accomodation Application</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
form div {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
</style>
<body>
<div>
    <div>
    <form>
        <p><a href="http://localhost/testwork/">Refresh</a></p>
        <div><label for="applicant-name">First Name</label><br /><input type="text" name="name" id="applicant-name"></div>
        <div><label for="applicant-surname">Surname</label><br /><input type="text" name="surname" id="applicant-surname"></div>
        <div><label for="applicant-identity">Smart ID Number</label><br /><input type="text" name="surname" id="applicant-identity"></div>
        <div id="town">
            <label for="applicant-town">Town</label><br />
            <select name="town" id="applicant-town"><option value="0">-- Select Town --</option>
            <?php
            $towns = mysqli_query($dbcon, "SELECT town_id, town_name FROM towns");
            while($town = mysqli_fetch_array($towns)){
                $town_id = $town['town_id'];
                $town_name = $town['town_name'];
                echo("<option value=\"$town_id\">$town_name</option>");
            }?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id="suburb">
            <label for="applicant-suburb">Suburb</label><br />
            <select name="suburb" id="applicant-suburb">
                <option value="0">-- Select Suburb --</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#applicant-town').change(function(){
        var suburb_town = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "suburbs.php",
            data: {town: suburb_town}
        })
        .done(function(data){
            alert(data);
            var burbs = JSON.parse(data);
            alert(burbs); // e.g. [{"1":"Halfway House"},{"2":"Noordwyk"},{"3":"Vorna Valley"}]
            $(burbs).each(burbs, function(key, value){
                $('#applicant-suburb').append('<option value="'+key+'">'+value+'</option>');
            });
        })
        .fail(function(){
            alert('There is an error somewhere.');
        });
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

suburbs.php

```
<?php
$dbcon = new mysqli (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
if(isset($_GET['town'])){
    $town_suburbs = array();
    $town_id = htmlspecialchars($_GET['town']);
    $suburbs = mysqli_query($dbcon, "SELECT suburb_id, suburb_name FROM suburbs WHERE suburb_town = $town_id");
    while($suburb = mysqli_fetch_array($suburbs)){
        $suburb_id = $suburb['suburb_id'];
        $suburb_name = $suburb['suburb_name'];
        $town_suburbs[] = array($suburb_id => $suburb_name);
    }
    echo json_encode($town_suburbs);
}
?>
```

Comment: Your each is iterating of an array of objects, so key will be the offset and the value will be the object.  You can then access the insides of the object with value["1"], value["2"], value["3"], the way you have your json currently structured.  Otherwise, if you want to be able to reference it with the key, don't return the elements as an object, just return them as string, so it's just an array of string.  At that point value would be the string. .... or as you have it you might could reference it with value[key + 1]

Comment: need to fix that structure , not practical at all using array index as object keys in your server output

Comment: Try `console.log(burbs)` to check if it is encoded properly (it should be, though). What I see is that you are probably not looping correctly. You probably wanted `$.each(burbs, function(i, val)` instead of `$(burbs).each(burbs, function(` . You should be using jQuery's .each prototype to loop the object. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: Oooooooooh I get it. using .each your "value" IS an object!

Comment: No, not always.  It can be.  It all depends on what is in your list. $(["mon", "tue", "wed"]).each(function(i, val){ /* val would be a string in this case */ });

Comment: @Taplar in this case yes it is an object , but with a bad structure as you noted about the array index as key,suggest keeping context of discussion as it pertains to OP code

Comment: yeppers, though I'm thinking he may want to tweak it some to accomidate that.  fixing to do an answer.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5yaj7La0/ This is the way he should be doing that. According to the E.G. Output, it will OF COURSE return object, because he is looping an ARRAY of objects, not the object itself, therefore he should first loop the array and, inside the loop, loop the object.

Comment: @Taplar, the challenge here is that the numeric values there are not in numerical order. They represent the id values from a database and may differ in their order, than they are here.

Comment: The answer I provided below changes the response to include the id as a field rather than the key of the data, that way in your looping you can focus entirely on the context of "this" rather than having to manipulate/guess at things based on the offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first off from the comments you can see what the issue is.  However, you may want to use your "id" for something so with that in mind you could do the following.

```
$town_suburbs[] = array($suburb_id => $suburb_name);
```

You could change that to

```
array_push($town_suburbs, array("id" => $suburb_id, "name" => $suburb_name));
```

Then on your javascript side...

```
$(burbs).each(burbs, function(key, value){
    $('#applicant-suburb').append('<option value="'+key+'">'+value+'</option>');
});
```

That could change to:

```
$(burbs).each(function(){
    $('#applicant-suburb').append('<option value="'+ this.id +'">'+ this.name +'</option>');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, man. This worked. I really appreciate your assistance. Once again, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use dataType: "json" in your statement ajax?

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "suburbs.php",
        data: {town: suburb_town}, 
        dataType: 'json'
})
```

Thus instead of making an "alert ()" you must make a "console.log" and analyze the content through the Javascript console your browser.

The Alert feature only shows "String" and therefore when attempting that shows you the content. The representation of an object in string is [object]. Therefore instead of console.log occupies alert ().

**update:** You can use alert (JSON.stringify (data)) to display the string in a alert.

**update2:** Your code will looks

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "suburbs.php",
        data: {town: suburb_town},
        dataType: 'json'
    })
    .done(function(data){
        console.log(data)
        });
    })
```

Comment: I tried adding dataType and used "console.log()" and the following is the error displayed ont the console:

Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [{"1":"Halfway House"},{"2":"Noordwyk"},{"3":"Vorna Valley"}]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, it was already saved as [Object Object]? 
Ensure that,

1. to decode a JSON string, use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)
2. to encode a JSON string, use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am encoding from a php array() variable, hence I used json_encode() in the suburb.php script. Unless I do not understand the second point.

Comment: this answer is just confusing the issue of how to handle the data structure. `$.ajax` will automatically do the parsing if used correctly

Comment: As you can see, you have a correctly decoded JSON. This is an array of Objects : `[{"1":"Halfway House"},{"2":"Noordwyk"},{"3":"Vorna Valley"}]`

Answer (score 0):

If your "E.G." is correct, then you are not looping (in javascript) in the correct way.

This:

```
$(burbs).each(burbs, function(key, value){
     $('#applicant-suburb').append('<option value="'+key+'">'+value+'</option>');
});
```

Should not work, because you have to loop an array of objects, therefore you first have to loop the array and, **then**, the objects:

```
for (var i = 0; i < burbs.length; ++i) {
    $.each(burbs[i], function(key, val) {
        $('#applicant-suburb').append('<option value="'+key+'">'+val+'</option>');
    });
}
```

According to your example, you can check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5yaj7La0/2/

As long as your current output has this structure:

```
[{"1":"Halfway House"},{"2":"Noordwyk"},{"3":"Vorna Valley"}];
```

You DON'T need to change your PHP code but if the output is different from that (it shouldn't, though), you may need to change your PHP code too.

HTML output :

[image]

(output is related to the fiddle, feel free to edit the names and tag and whatever, the important thing here is the Javascript).

Answer (score 0):

If you get `[Object object]` by doing :

```
var burbs = JSON.parse(data);//alerting this will definitely present [Object object]
```

Then everything seems to be fine.

You are parsing the data and this will be converted to a json object.

If you want to view the response data use :

```
var burbs = JSON.stringify(data);//converts the object to a string
alert(burbs);
```

Also probably you want to get the values by accessing the keys of each object within the object array:

```
//lets imagine this is our response data, which can also be the response data you parsed with JSON.parse(data);

var data = [{"1":"Halfway House"},{"2":"Noordwyk"},{"3":"Vorna Valley"}];

function iterate(data)
{
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
    {
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
        {
            for(var key in data[i])
            {
                var value = data[i][key];
                $('#applicant-suburb').append('<option value="'+key+'">'+value+'</option>');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Can the problem be with the fact that you are missing a header() statement in your suburb.php file?

Something like

Comment: I doubt it was. Although I remember reading somewhere that it should be there. Anyway, Taplar's answer worked. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I really see no reason for downvoting me, but ok XD